# Guan Yin - Bodhisattva as Goddess of Mercy

Tags: doubt

Where can I find the sanskrit or original version that mentioning Guan Yin is "Goddess of Mercy" as this wording popping up everywhere online.

The word "God" really needs to be carefully written and respected.

I understand many misconceptions from most famous Buddhism movie and one of the top 4 Novel of China which is Journey to The West. I am not sure the wording is from the movie or novel evolution?

The movie script writing and Buddhism teaching way too much difference yet making people claimed himself as Buddhist more superstitious or dont even know who is Buddha or worship at temple of out nothing.

Post ques remarks
Seem the naming is from Christian and not Buddhism Sangha/community [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesuit_China_missions#:~:text=The%20missionary%20efforts%20and%20other,culture%20in%20Chinese%20society%20today](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesuit_China_missions#:%7E:text=The%20missionary%20efforts%20and%20other,culture%20in%20Chinese%20society%20today).

Comment: Wikipedia says, `She was first given the appellation of "Goddess of Mercy" or the Mercy Goddess by Jesuit missionaries in China.`

Comment: @ChrisW then misconception and praying out of nothing or worship with zero guide or worship with zero knowledge is seem inappropriate and strangely nobody says anything? it's more like a commercialize place or tourism place for most of the temple. That's how i spent my 10 years lingering at the temple to seek the truth.

Comment: nobody says anything --> answer from most of the Buddhism teaching class is a true Buddhism needs certain level of credit or faith to learn that.Also written in the Sutra at the opening verse - "Is difficult to encounter throughout hundreds of
thousands of millions of kalpas." https://www.fgsitc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Ksitigarbha_Sutra_ChiEng.pdf

Comment: On the subject of Jesuits, "Mother of Mercy" is one of Mary's titles. I can't say that [those concepts](http://www.catholictradition.org/Mary/mother-savior16.htm) are useless -- perhaps they're more or less like the Buddhist brahmaviiharas, for example -- and contemplating Mary's losing her son, might have an effect on the audience like [this story](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/noncanon/comy/thiga-10-01-ao0.html) (i.e. knowing that other people have this trouble too). But I'm glad people on this site introduced me to more detailed Buddhist doctrine, my sources before this were more shallow.

Comment: So is this question unanswerable?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be asking for an impossible (non-existent) reference, i.e. for a Sanskrit reference which describes Guan Yin as a "Goddess".